# Dropdown needs to go to value assigned on submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, forms

"document.location" runs it immediately after it's clicked. I need it to run after submit. . . Any Suggestions?

For reference: [First Tennessee Bank](https://www.firsttennessee.com/)

```
<form>
<select name="mydropdown" class="styled" onchange="document.location = this.value" value="GO">
        <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
        <option value="http://fb.com">Facebook</option>
        <option value="http://youtube.com">Youtube</option>
</select>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: What's with the single quotes in the question title?

Comment: You don't have `document.location` anywhere in your code.

Comment: It was where .submit was.

Comment: Remove the change listener from the select, and add a submit listener to the form instead.

Comment: @Teemu That doesn't seem to work. http://jsfiddle.net/hPdm3/63/

Comment: Huh! I'd almost say you're trolling here ... "_add a submit listener_".

Comment: Could solve a lot of headaches and just succumb to the joys of jquery ......

Comment: Do you actually need the submision? If there's a server-side code responsing, you could pass the value to the server, and then redirect to a correct site with the server response. If the submission is not needed, change the type of submit input to a button input, and use its onclick handler to change the location.

Comment: @Teemu Can you show me an example; I tried it, but I am not sure if I understand you.

Comment: At first I've to know if you really have to submit the form. Though Scath seems already have posted a working answer (In the case the submission is not needed).

Comment: @Teemu No I do not, just change the page to the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you are wanting to do when they click submit it will go do the location they picked.

```js
function go(){
var x =document.getElementsByClassName('styled')[0]
document.location = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select name="mydropdown" class="styled" c value="GO">
    <option value="http://www.google.com">Google</option>
    <option value="http://fb.com">Facebook</option>
    <option value="http://youtube.com">Youtube</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="go()">
</form>
```

Comment: Not going to work, pending submission blocks the changes to `location`. Notice, that the sandboxed Stack Snippet works different on this case (it wouldn't submit the form anyway, hence `location` changes are not blocked).

Comment: Yep, or canceling the default action, omitting the form, redirecting on the server ...

Comment: It wont submit the form though hmm could add an ID to the form and document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

Comment: Then the redirection wouldn't work. The only way to get both the submission and redirection done is to redirect at the server-side, or do everything with AJAX.

Comment: @Scath Brillant, Thank you!